# ng-bootstrap directives not compiled

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Hi I've created a new angular (5.2) app with angular cli
I've added ng-bootstrap (1.0.0-beta.9) and bootstrap (4.0.0) as dependancies.

here's an exctract of my package.json file

```
  "dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
   "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
   "core-js": "^2.4.1",
   "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
   "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
 }
```

In .angular-cli.json file i've added this

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js"
  ]
```

in my root module I've this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  currentRate = 8;
}
```

And in my app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate"></ngb-rating>
```

the directive ngb-rating shows nothing

Could you please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: that's done, it's "magically" working now

Comment: You do _not_ need `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js` in your scripts, ng-bootstrap is re-implementing Bootstrap's JS logic. You need CSS only.